# Referenced assembly 'Google.Apis.Drive.v2' does not have a strong name

Tags: .net, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client, strongname

I am working on project in which I am using Google Drive API. The current version of the Google .net client library dlls are not strong name signed.  I need my project to be signed.  When I tried and sign the project .dll into strongly type when I do it throws exception that

**Referenced assembly 'Google.Apis.Drive.v2' does not have a strong name**

same with other Google DLL's

How do i convert Google's weakly type assembly into strongly typed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the source for all of the client library [Google-api-dotnet-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client) includeing the source code for [Google.Apis.Drive.v2](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/download/drive/v2/csharp).  Also you have to update the [zlib](https://github.com/advancedrei/Zlib.Portable) to the [new signed version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Zlib.Portable.Signed/). You will need to sign all the libraries and build the project. For it to work all the libraries have to be signed.

or you could just wait another week or so we are in the process of testing the next version which will address issue [238: release signed dlls](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/238).

[The test version is hear I think](https://github.com/peleyal/google-api-dotnet-client)

Answer (score 0):

Like Linda just mentioned, in a week or two we are going to release a new version of the client library with signed version. Release 1.9.2 will include a singed version of the core Google.Apis libraries and also the generated libraries as well.

Stay tuned to our announcement blog - http://google-api-dotnet-client.blogspot.com/